# MIME Type Error for Javascript file - VS Code/Live server - Firefox/Console

Tags: javascript, dictionary, firefox, mime

I try to open html/js file using VS Code/liveServer/firefox/console, and I get the following errors

I have searched google for answers and had a look on the firefox 'learn more' linked to the errors but I don't know enough to use the information, if there is a file to modify or an error in my basic html file (which I think is ok because it worked yesterday) then for me just a point in the right direction would be good! ;o)

The resource from “http://localhost:5500/js/script.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
Source map error: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
Resource URL: moz-extension://e3e6edd3-45b6-47f8-895b-6e7fa20f8f13/browser-polyfill.js
Source Map URL: browser-polyfill.js.map[Learn More]
The resource from “http://localhost:5500/js/script.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).[Learn More] localhost:5500
Loading failed for the  with source “http://localhost:5500/js/script.js”.

CODE  HTML

`

```js
console.log('test')
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>c0de-geek-js-1</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" href="../css/styles.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

My code is a basic html bootstrap with 'script' text/javascript ../js/script.js '/script' (brackets omitted) there is no complicated code just basic it worked yesterday but today I get the error above and it's confusing for that alone as it worked, any ideas would be good I am pretty good with google but this I am not sure where to start, many thanks in advance!

I created a GitHub repo if that makes any difference I loaded it through VS Code but all that I have done before and as I said it worked yesterday???

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow :). Can you add the code that causes your problem, please?

Comment: Hi there ;o) it's just basic code from what I have read it's a problem with MIME types and the fetch API with this error Source map error: --> TypeError NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. Resource URL: moz-extension://e3e6edd3-45b6-47f8-895b-6e7fa20f8f13/browser-polyfill.js Source Map URL: browser-polyfill.js.map I have 20 tabs open atm but it's quite complicated for me right now to do with CORS and MIME sniffing if there is a file I can edit or a correct API but I'm not familiar enough to be more precise just my basic code and the error, thanks dude! ;o)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this finds whomever searches for a solution. Change the name of the css and js files to style and script respectively.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).